# Decrypting AES encrypted password to plain text in PowerShell Script

Tags: powershell, encryption, cryptography

I have been following along on numerous how-to articles that explain how to decrypt an AES encrypted password. No matter how I try, the password ends up with $password displaying as System.Security.SecureString. I need the password to echo in plain text because I am calling a command line utility that does not use windows permissions (ADSI/LDAP). Here's my script:

```
$PasswordFile = "$PSScriptRoot\PowerShell\AESpassword.txt" 
$KeyFile = "$PSScriptRoot\PowerShell\AES.key" 
$key = Get-Content $KeyFile
$MyPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString (Get-Content $PasswordFile | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $key) -AsPlainText -Force
$Marshal = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]
$BSTR = $Marshal::SecureStringToBSTR($MyPassword)
$password = $Marshal::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)
```

Comment: Why two calls to `ConvertTo-SecureString`? `$MyPassword = Get-Content $PasswordFile | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $key` should suffice

Comment: Yeah, you first call `ConvertTo-SecureString` on the decrypted password and then complain that it is a secure string?!?

Comment: Your suggestion to use $MyPassword = Get-Content $PasswordFile | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $key worked like a charm! Thank you so much! Make sure to post that comment as the answer so I can give you credit for it. :)

Comment: bbcompent1 - Tip: use `@username` to ensure @MathiasRJessen is notified of your comment asking him to promote the comment to an answer :-)

Comment: @MathiasRJessen Your suggestion to use $MyPassword = Get-Content $PasswordFile | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $key worked like a charm! Thank you so much! Make sure to post that comment as the answer so I can give you credit for it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @MathiasRJessen the suggestion to use $MyPassword = Get-Content $PasswordFile | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $key worked like a charm! Thank you so much! Make sure to post that comment as the answer so I can give you credit for it. :)